# How do I run jshint with rhino?

Tags: javascript, java, windows, jshint

I'm trying to use jshint to clean up some of my JavaScript however I am running into problems using it. The command I am trying to run is `java -jar js.jar jshint-rhino.js app.js` where

- `js.jar` is part of the Rhino binary which I downloaded from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Download_Rhino).
- `jshint-rhino.js` is from the javascript file from the jshint [repository on github](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/tree/b554ffe/dist).
- app.js is my application's code.

The error I am getting is

> js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: TypeError: Cannot read property "prototype" from undefined

What I am expecting to happen is for the command to render a long list of complaints about my undoubtedly sub-par JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a know [issue](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/2308). To get things working I just used the 2.6.3 version [jshint-rhino.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jshint/jshint/2.6.3/dist/jshint-rhino.js).